# How to stop column content from going into the wrong column in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I am doing some work in bootstrap, I am trying to have one column on the left which will give some info and another collection of columns on the right that will contain images.

So far I have tried the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However when I added the fifth `col-md-2` it pushed it below `col-md-4` whereas I want it to stay underneath the first `col-md-2`.

See below for what I want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAR8d.png)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you must need to change your code like below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          hello
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```